# mongoose .remove stopped working for one particular model, why?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I defined a model Group similar to all my models but while testing my routes noticed that my mocha test timed out on DELETE

I kept debugging and found that the callback for model.remove() was not being called
`findByIdAndRemove` worked, so did `findOneAndRemove`and I reduced the model shcema to its bare bones so why god, why!! isn't it working.

```
var GroupSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: {
       type: String,
       default: function() {
           return generateName();
       }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out I had defined

```
GroupSchema.methods.add = function(user) {
  //TODO
};


GroupSchema.methods.remove = function(user) {
  //TODO
};
```

and left it empty which override the mongoose remove method -__-

I love Javascript but this is one of those moments where protecting functions from override would have been nice.

of course it wouldn't be simple, I would like to override a function and call it if I want, so it's not like I can complain about the feature.

thought of sharing my experience out there so that I might save someone else the frustration.

I think a good way to approach this from now on is to namespace my custom methods which is impractical
or generally just leave a console.log on empty methods that are under construction so that  I know if they're called.